# Swift Storing Appending multiple Dictionary into array

Tags: swift3

I want to store multiple dictionary into an array so that the final results looks like so

```
(
   {
     id: 12,
     task : completed
   },
   {
     id: 15,
     task : error
   },
   {
     id: 17,
     task : pending
   },
)
```

I tried with code below but it does not give me what I want Please can someone help me out. Thanks

```
var FinalTaskData = [[String:AnyObject]]()
            for i in 0..<taskObj.count{
                let dict = ["id":taskObj[i].id!,"task":taskObj[i].task!] as [String : AnyObject]
                FinalTaskData.append(dict)
            }
```

And this gives me the output of

```
(
        {
        id = 190;
    },
        {
        task = "Task To Be Edited";
    },
        {
        id = 191;
    },
        {
        task = "Also To Be Edited";
    }
)
```

Which is not what I want. Thanks

Comment: The output doesn't match the code. Why do you want to convert a specific type (apparently a struct or class) to an unspecific dictionary? Actually in Swift you can do it with one line using `map`. And this dictionary is `[String:Any]` in Swift 3+.

Comment: Am new in swift. its a class. Please could you guid ne on how to solve my problem? thanks

Comment: Once again, why? Swift is a strong-type language and a class is more type-safe than a dictionary. And the code cannot generate this output.

Comment: I am looping through an instance of the class to create my dictionary. I am not converting the class into a dictionary

Comment: @Mohammed What is the type of **taskObj**?